How to fix: “Safari” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash."
I tried terminal commands provided in Youtube videos specific to this problem, failed. I booted into Recovery mode and reinstalled my system OS (Sonoma 14.6.1 - M1 imac), then exited and restarted my computer. That still did not remove these persistent pop-ups that interrupt all work on computer.

If you know that you've made a copy of Safari, including any backups of the System volume, delete the copy. If you're not sure, search for it in Spotlight.

Here is that Apple Support response page:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/102564
This is where I got idea to maybe reinstall the OS so that Safari.app is reinstalled fresh.  That did not work. I still get these errors. The "PART 2 POPUP" appears after you click "Move to Trash" button. After you click that, a second error message pops up, but I can't find a screenshot image. It contains an actuator button in Red.

@UXdesigner Can't you just take the screenshots yourself? As per importing images, just drag and drop them to the answer field (or click the image icon in the toolbar at the top of the answer field and choose how you want to import it).

@Thinkr  thanks you for trying to help me. I tried several times to edit my original question to add the 2 popup error images, trying both the browse/attach method and the drag & drop method. The system rejected both saying there was a problem.  I thought perhaps they were exceeding filesize max, so i scaled them way down to middle-level jpegs. Still didn't work. I think I lack the basic ability to use these forums.

It would help a lot if you could answer the question I asked 2 days ago. Are there any copies of Safari anywhere on your system, or anything with the name "Safari"? It's absolutely impossible for the original Safari to be corrupted. If it were, your Mac wouldn't boot at all.

Thanks for the edits! Please delete the part where I put in you need to show your research if you can.  Otherwise, better to not even waste space and energy with “I searched everywhere and nothing worked” type information. Hit us up on [meta] if you need help unloading images. We can assist

@Linc Davis — Sorry for long delay. Not to my knowledge are there any other copies on my laptop system. Didn't show when I searched via Finder, nor when I did a finer search using 3rd party app "Find Any File". ... I did get a newer Macbook pro and this issue now no longer exists.

I would probably start with downloading Safari tech preview and see if that is stable.

https://webkit.org/downloads/

At the same time, I would double down on backing up all your important data or set up Time Machine to an external drive and let all your dat and programs back up regularly.
Next steps are going to be to repair the disk, reinstall the OS, erase install the OS in that order.
